# How to handle this Redux Store scenario when mapStateToProps is not called

Tags: react-redux

I learn React Redux and basically what happen is that when user type wrong words  there is an action `dispatch` from the Redux `middleware` to the `Store`.

The `Store` State gets updated with this "wrong word" and a Notification Component have the `mapStateToProps` for this "wrong word" and all work well the Notification gets displayed about a "wrong word".

My problem is that in the `Store` the "wrong word" is stored as a string so if user type the same word twice the `mapStateToProps` is not fired because the `Store` State for "wrong word" did not change.

How should I change this so it works for same word twice?
I have tested making "wrong word" as an array and that works but the intention is not to keep an array of bad words.

The detection of "wrong word" is not an important part of the app overall system structure so maybe the `Store` "wrong word" is not necessary but how then should the `middleware` propagate this directly to Notification React.Component.

I understand the answer might be opinionated but I´m new to Redux and must ask to learn.

Comment: Just dispatch one more action that will clear the `wrong word` in the store once you display the notification.

Comment: Thanks, if I clear the word then the word changes and won't that fire a new 'mapStateToProps', or is there a way to stop that

Comment: Your component will render again as there was a change in props, from no empty to empty. You can just put a notification behind a truthy check. Only display when the wrong word is non empty.